# Автоматические поддомены в apache + nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu

Хочу сделать так, чтобы если в папке любого сайта создается категория sub_имяавтоматически создавался поддомен имя.site.ru

На сервере связка nginx, как фронт энд к apacheстоит ubuntu 12.10Есть ли примеры концигов для apache и nginx, где можно реализовать подобное?

В принципе, я мог бы сделать это сам, вставив в нужные места в конфигах регулярные.Вопрос такой, заработает ли все, если в существующем конфиге прописать регэкспы?Может поможете тогда и с регулярными? (с ними я плох)А лучше пример конфига готового.

Comment: а зачем вам apache?

Answer (score 1):

В нгинксе вполне себе используются регулярки, в апаче в конфиге - не уверен. В апаче видимо через `.htaccess` надо рулить будет.